# What's the path for Jitsi config files?

Tags: software, facetime, macos, path

As near as I can tell, Jitsi is able to dial out and make a phone call using babytel:

```
17:35:39.320 INFO: [881] impl.protocol.sip.OperationSetBasicTelephonySipImpl.createOutgoingCall().184 Creating outgoing call to sip:1234567890@sip.babytel.ca
17:35:41.543 INFO: [923] plugin.reconnectplugin.ReconnectPluginActivator.run().610 Reconnect 1234567890@sip.babytel.ca (SIP) after 3000 ms.
17:35:41.559 INFO: [866] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been stopped
17:35:42.561 INFO: [866] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been stopped
17:35:44.544 INFO: [997] plugin.reconnectplugin.ReconnectPluginActivator.run().973 Start reconnecting 1234567890@sip.babytel.ca (SIP)
17:35:44.545 WARNING: [997] service.resources.AbstractResourcesService.getSettingsInt().596 Missing resource for key: net.java.sip.communicator.SIP_PREFERRED_CLEAR_PORT
17:35:44.545 INFO: [997] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been started
17:35:44.547 WARNING: [997] service.resources.AbstractResourcesService.getSettingsInt().596 Missing resource for key: net.java.sip.communicator.SIP_PREFERRED_SECURE_PORT
17:35:44.731 SEVERE: [1012] impl.protocol.sip.EventPackageSubscriber.processResponse().776 no Expires header in this response
17:35:45.022 WARNING: [1013] impl.protocol.sip.SipStackSharing.processResponse().732 Transaction is null, probably already expired! Status=180
17:35:54.515 WARNING: [1014] impl.protocol.sip.SipStackSharing.processResponse().732 Transaction is null, probably already expired! Status=200
17:35:55.189 WARNING: [1015] impl.protocol.sip.SipStackSharing.processResponse().732 Transaction is null, probably already expired! Status=200
17:35:56.389 WARNING: [1016] impl.protocol.sip.SipStackSharing.processResponse().732 Transaction is null, probably already expired! Status=200
17:35:57.990 WARNING: [1017] impl.protocol.sip.SipStackSharing.processResponse().732 Transaction is null, probably already expired! Status=200
17:36:00.190 WARNING: [1018] impl.protocol.sip.SipStackSharing.processResponse().732 Transaction is null, probably already expired! Status=200
17:36:06.005 SEVERE: [1021] impl.protocol.sip.ProxyRouter.getRouterFor().153 unable to identify the service which created this out-of-dialog request
17:36:06.090 SEVERE: [1021] util.UtilActivator.uncaughtException().108 An uncaught exception occurred in thread=Thread[Thread-988,6,main] and message was: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gov.nist.javax.sip.SipProviderImpl.getNewClientTransaction(SipProviderImpl.java:401)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.protocol.sip.CallPeerSipImpl.sayCancel(CallPeerSipImpl.java:1117)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.protocol.sip.CallPeerSipImpl.hangup(CallPeerSipImpl.java:1022)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.protocol.sip.OperationSetBasicTelephonySipImpl.hangupCallPeer(OperationSetBasicTelephonySipImpl.java:1929)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.protocol.sip.OperationSetBasicTelephonySipImpl.hangupCallPeer(OperationSetBasicTelephonySipImpl.java:1907)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.gui.main.call.CallManager$HangupCallThread.run(CallManager.java:3306)
17:36:16.708 INFO: [1026] plugin.reconnectplugin.ReconnectPluginActivator.run().610 Reconnect 1234567890@sip.babytel.ca (SIP) after 5000 ms.
17:36:16.722 INFO: [999] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been stopped
17:36:17.724 INFO: [999] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been stopped
17:36:21.711 INFO: [1027] plugin.reconnectplugin.ReconnectPluginActivator.run().973 Start reconnecting 1234567890@sip.babytel.ca (SIP)
17:36:21.711 WARNING: [1027] service.resources.AbstractResourcesService.getSettingsInt().596 Missing resource for key: net.java.sip.communicator.SIP_PREFERRED_CLEAR_PORT
17:36:21.711 INFO: [1027] impl.protocol.sip.SipLogger.logInfo().185 Info from the JAIN-SIP stack: the sip stack timer gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.timers.DefaultSipTimer has been started
17:36:21.714 WARNING: [1027] service.resources.AbstractResourcesService.getSettingsInt().596 Missing resource for key: net.java.sip.communicator.SIP_PREFERRED_SECURE_PORT
17:36:21.895 SEVERE: [1042] impl.protocol.sip.EventPackageSubscriber.processResponse().776 no Expires header in this response
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$
```

but where are the settings for accounts actually stored?  The configuration files?

```
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ 
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ find -name sip-communicator.properties
find: illegal option -- n
find: illegal option -- a
find: illegal option -- m
find: illegal option -- e
find: sip-communicator.properties: No such file or directory
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ 
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ 
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$ find -name "sip-communicator.properties"
find: illegal option -- n
find: illegal option -- a
find: illegal option -- m
find: illegal option -- e
find: sip-communicator.properties: No such file or directory
Brents-MacBook:~ thufir$
```

I also tried a search of "this mac" from the Finder GUI.

Comment: ~/Library/Application Support/Jitsi

Comment: Jitsi’s main configuration file is called sip-communicator.properties

Comment: `Library/Application\ Support/Jitsi/sip-communicator.properties`  thanks @Buscar웃

Comment: The find isn't Gnu find, and requires the path as the first argument. See the man page.  Searching from the Finder requires adding a filter, 'System Files' 'are included'.